# Como acessar no ViewModel, uma ListView q esta em uma View?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin-forms, xamarin.android

Então tenho uma page q se chama FilmeView nela eu tenho: 
`<ListView BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke" SeparatorColor="Blue" x:Name="listaFilme">` e eu tenho uma classe de ViewModel:

```
 FilmeService filmeService = new FilmeService(); 
 var lista = filmeService.GetAll().Result;
 // (quero usar a propriedade x:Name do list view nessa classe)
```

Porem quando eu vou colocar `listaFilme.itemsSource` ele não consegue vincular essa ListView q veio do FilmeView, minha dúvida é como eu vinculo a classe View no meu view model para eu acessar essa ListView para mostrar os dados?

Comment: Esse vínculo é feito recomendavelmente através de um padrão chamado MVVM com os recursos de Binding que o `Xamarin` tem nativo. Consulta os primeiros passos na [documentação oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/xamarin/xamarin-forms/) que vai te ajudar. Sua pergunta é muito ampla, difícil ajudar,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá @Guilherme Petena!

Embora essa não seja uma prática recomendada pela Microsoft durante a construção de apps utilizando Xamarin([vide documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm) para saber mais)

Você consegue isso que vc está falando através da seguinte forma:

supondo que sua View se chama `MinhaView` no seu construtor eu faço o binding da viewModel e ao mesmo tempo passo para viewModel que irá se chamar `MinhaViewModel` a referência da página que está vinculada.

Feito isso a ViewModel terá a referência para a página que agora basta utilziar o método `FindByName` da mesma para obter o controle da mesma.

como pode ser visto abaixo:

```
public class MinhaViewModel {

    private Page _paginaRelacionada;

    public MinhaViewModel(Page paginaRelacionada){
        _paginaRelacionada = paginaRelacionada;
    }

    public bool TentarObterElementoDaPagina(string elementName, object elementoProcurado){
       elementoProcurado = _paginaRelacionada?.FindByName(elementName);
       return elementoProcurado != null;        
    }
}


public partial class MinhaView {

    public MinhaView() {

     var viewModel = new MinhaViewModel(this);
     BindingContext = viewModel;

    }


}
```

Obs. Esta técnica não funciona para controles que estão dentro de template, como por exemplo, no caso do template dos itens de uma listView